# Findenode failed using bootnode in local geth network: invalid IP in response record: loopback address from non-loopback host

Tags: docker, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I followed an "old" tutorial (from 2018) about [Building a local Ethereum network with Docker and Geth](https://medium.com/@javahippie/building-a-local-ethereum-network-with-docker-and-geth-5b9326b85f37) which is great but "deprecated" for `Geth/v1.9.17`. So i tried to come up with a new version for my studies.

The `Dockerfile`'s and `docker-compose.yml` can be found [here](https://github.com/myronrotter/simple-geth-network). This dockerized setup should spin up a bootnode and two miners utilizing PoA. However, the miners do not sync or find each other leading to a `Findenode failed` error in the docker logs. (They do not seal new blocks.)

`geth js console` of one miner shows

```
.../simple-geth-network$ docker exec -ti 7dd9c5068bed /bin/bash
root@geth-miner1:~# geth attach
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.9.17-stable-748f22c1/linux-amd64/go1.14.2
coinbase: 0x8cc5a1a0802db41db826c2fcb72423744338dcb0
at block: 1 (Sun Jul 26 2020 09:54:51 GMT+0000 (UTC))
 datadir: /root/.ethereum
 modules: admin:1.0 clique:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 shh:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> eth.blockNumber
1
> net.peerCount
0
> admin.peers
[]
```

Nevertheless, if I add a peer via `geth js console` and `admin.addPeer()` both miners are in sync and are sealing new blocks.

I have read about sync failures due to out of sync clocks (time), but I checked an both miners clocks are in sync.

Here is a snipped of one miners docker logs trace:

```
.../simple-geth-network$ docker logs -f b198e971af76
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.521] Sanitizing Go's GC trigger               percent=100
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.521] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
WARN [07-26|09:54:51.521] The flag --rpc is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --http 
WARN [07-26|09:54:51.522] The flag --rpcaddr is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --http.addr 
WARN [07-26|09:54:51.522] The flag --rpcapi is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --http.api 
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.522] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.522] FS scan times                            list="252.404µs" set="23.397µs" diff="10.965µs"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.522] Handled keystore changes                 time="178.792µs"
WARN [07-26|09:54:51.522] The flag --etherbase is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --miner.etherbase 
WARN [07-26|09:54:51.522] The flag --gasprice is deprecated and will be removed in the future, please use --miner.gasprice 
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.523] Set global gas cap                       cap=25000000
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.523] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.9.17-stable-748f22c1/linux-amd64/go1.14.2
WARN [07-26|09:54:51.523] Sanitizing invalid miner gas price       provided=0 updated=0
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.523] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=256.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.523] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=524288
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.526] Started watching keystore folder         path=/root/.ethereum/keystore
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.559] Chain freezer table opened               database=/root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient table=headers items=0 size=0.00B
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.563] Chain freezer table opened               database=/root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient table=hashes  items=0 size=0.00B
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.566] Chain freezer table opened               database=/root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient table=bodies  items=0 size=0.00B
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.570] Chain freezer table opened               database=/root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient table=receipts items=0 size=0.00B
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.574] Chain freezer table opened               database=/root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient table=diffs    items=0 size=0.00B
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.574] Opened ancient database                  database=/root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.574] Current full block not old enough        number=0 hash="62f584…23ba54" delay=90000
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.574] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1337 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 4 Constantinople: <nil> Petersburg: <nil> Istanbul: <nil>, Muir Glacier: <nil>, YOLO v1: <nil>, Engine: clique}"
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.575] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[65 64 63]" network=1337 dbversion=<nil>
WARN [07-26|09:54:51.575] Upgrade blockchain database version      from=<nil> to=7
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.576] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash="62f584…23ba54" td=1 age=2y5mo2w
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.576] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash="62f584…23ba54" td=1 age=2y5mo2w
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.576] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash="62f584…23ba54" td=1 age=2y5mo2w
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.576] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.577] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.577] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.578] Stored checkpoint snapshot to disk       number=0 hash="62f584…23ba54"
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.592] UDP listener up                          addr=[::]:30303
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.592] TCP listener up                          addr=[::]:30303
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.597] Found seed node in database              id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 age=443265h54m51.597651988s
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.598] New local node record                    seq=1 id=09423dfc6b6e821f ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.599] started whisper v.6.0 
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.601] InProc registered                        namespace=admin
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.601] InProc registered                        namespace=admin
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.601] InProc registered                        namespace=debug
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.601] InProc registered                        namespace=web3
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.602] InProc registered                        namespace=eth
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.602] Found seed node in database              id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 age=443265h54m51.602618989s
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.603] >> PING/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.602] InProc registered                        namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.603] InProc registered                        namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.603] InProc registered                        namespace=txpool
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.603] InProc registered                        namespace=debug
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.603] InProc registered                        namespace=debug
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.603] InProc registered                        namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.604] InProc registered                        namespace=personal
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.604] InProc registered                        namespace=clique
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.604] InProc registered                        namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.604] InProc registered                        namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.604] InProc registered                        namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.604] InProc registered                        namespace=miner
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.604] Starting p2p dial                        id=8d5107cf4e03772d ip=172.25.0.101 flag=dyndial
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.604] InProc registered                        namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.604] InProc registered                        namespace=admin
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.604] InProc registered                        namespace=debug
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.605] Dial error                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 conn=dyndial err="connect: connection refused"
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.601] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://166ed53a196caeaf96d78625bfe1ec557ea21d379e77f8e8d177c9851e7a6869e141f65f49a3dd05752a285df01e150154cff056571f339c9967ccbc7d0c7f0a@127.0.0.1:30303
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.605] >> PING/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.605] InProc registered                        namespace=debug
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.605] InProc registered                        namespace=net
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.605] InProc registered                        namespace=shh
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.605] << PONG/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.606] << PING/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.606] >> PONG/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.607] IPC registered                           namespace=admin
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.607] IPC registered                           namespace=admin
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.607] IPC registered                           namespace=debug
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.607] IPC registered                           namespace=web3
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.607] IPC registered                           namespace=eth
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.607] << PONG/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.607] IPC registered                           namespace=eth
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.607] << PING/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:51.608] >> PONG/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.609] IPC registered                           namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.610] IPC registered                           namespace=txpool
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.610] IPC registered                           namespace=debug
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.611] IPC registered                           namespace=debug
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.612] IPC registered                           namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.613] IPC registered                           namespace=personal
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=clique
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=miner
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=eth
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=admin
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=debug
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=debug
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=net
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:51.614] IPC registered                           namespace=shh
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.615] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/root/.ethereum/geth.ipc
INFO [07-26|09:54:51.617] HTTP endpoint opened                     url=http://[::]:8545/        cors= vhosts=localhost
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.106] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.108] << NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.108] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.109] << NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.606] Findnode failed                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=1 results=0 err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.607] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.608] << NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.609] Findnode failed                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=1 results=0 err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.609] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.610] Discarding dial candidate                id=8d5107cf4e03772d ip=172.25.0.101 reason="recently dialed"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:52.610] << NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
INFO [07-26|09:54:53.015] Unlocked account                         address=0x3590ACA93338b0721966a8d0C96EbF2C4c87c544
INFO [07-26|09:54:53.017] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=0
INFO [07-26|09:54:53.017] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=0
INFO [07-26|09:54:53.017] Commit new mining work                   number=1 sealhash="9e199e…786fa9" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="192.76µs"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.017] Out-of-turn signing requested            wiggle=1s
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.017] Waiting for slot to sign and propagate   delay=531.569ms
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.108] Findnode failed                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=2 results=0 err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.108] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.109] << NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.109] Findnode failed                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=2 results=0 err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.110] Discarding dial candidate                id=8d5107cf4e03772d ip=172.25.0.101 reason="recently dialed"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.110] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.111] << NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
INFO [07-26|09:54:53.550] Successfully sealed new block            number=1 sealhash="9e199e…786fa9" hash="0afdfc…1c473d" elapsed=533.111ms
INFO [07-26|09:54:53.550]  mined potential block                  number=1 hash="0afdfc…1c473d"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.550] Propagated block                         hash="0afdfc…1c473d" recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.550] Announced block                          hash="0afdfc…1c473d" recipients=0 duration=2562047h47m16.854s
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:53.550] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
INFO [07-26|09:54:53.551] Commit new mining work                   number=2 sealhash="5b3591…0e0fa6" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="527.016µs"
INFO [07-26|09:54:53.551] Signed recently, must wait for others 
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.609] Findnode failed                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=3 results=0 err="RPC timeout"
INFO [07-26|09:54:53.610] New local node record                    seq=2 id=09423dfc6b6e821f ip=127.0.0.1    udp=30303 tcp=30303
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.610] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.610] Findnode failed                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=3 results=0 err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.610] Discarding dial candidate                id=8d5107cf4e03772d ip=172.25.0.101 reason="recently dialed"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.611] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.612] << NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.612] << NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:53.692] Couldn't add port mapping                proto=tcp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPnP or NAT-PMP" err="no UPnP or NAT-PMP router discovered"
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:53.692] Couldn't add port mapping                proto=udp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPnP or NAT-PMP" err="no UPnP or NAT-PMP router discovered"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.761] >> PING/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.763] << PONG/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.763] >> ENRREQUEST/v4                         id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:53.765] << ENRRESPONSE/v4                        id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:53.765] ENR request failed                       id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err="invalid IP in response record: invalid IP"
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:53.766] Revalidated node                         b=16 id=8d5107cf4e03772d checks=1
TRACE[07-26|09:54:54.110] Findnode failed                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=4 results=0 err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:54.111] Findnode failed                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=4 results=0 err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:54.111] Discarding dial candidate                id=8d5107cf4e03772d ip=172.25.0.101 reason="recently dialed"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:54.111] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:54.113] << NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:54.611] Findnode failed                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=5 results=0 err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:54.611] Too many findnode failures, dropping     id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=5
TRACE[07-26|09:54:58.705] << PING/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:58.705] >> PONG/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:58.707] << ENRREQUEST/v4                         id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:58.707] >> ENRRESPONSE/v4                        id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:58.832] >> PING/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:58.833] << PONG/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:58.834] >> ENRREQUEST/v4                         id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:58.834] << ENRRESPONSE/v4                        id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:58.835] ENR request failed                       id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err="invalid IP in response record: invalid IP"
DEBUG[07-26|09:54:58.835] Revalidated node                         b=16 id=8d5107cf4e03772d checks=1
TRACE[07-26|09:54:59.613] Discarding dial candidate                id=8d5107cf4e03772d ip=172.25.0.101 reason="node does not provide TCP port"
TRACE[07-26|09:54:59.613] >> FINDNODE/v4                           id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:54:59.615] << NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:55:00.113] Findnode failed                          id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=6 results=0 err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[07-26|09:55:00.114] Too many findnode failures, dropping     id=8d5107cf4e03772d failcount=6
TRACE[07-26|09:55:01.414] << PING/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:55:01.415] >> PONG/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:55:01.416] << ENRREQUEST/v4                         id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:55:01.416] >> ENRRESPONSE/v4                        id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:55:01.420] << PING/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:55:01.421] >> PONG/v4                               id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:55:01.422] << ENRREQUEST/v4                         id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:55:01.422] >> ENRRESPONSE/v4                        id=8d5107cf4e03772d addr=172.25.0.101:30301 err=nil
TRACE[07-26|09:55:02.114] Discarding dial candidate                id=8d5107cf4e03772d ip=172.25.0.101 reason="node does not provide TCP port"
INFO [07-26|09:55:02.114] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=1 static=0
```

EDIT: Here is a snippet of the docker log trace of the bootnode:

```
TRACE[07-27|19:40:44.808] << FINDNODE/v4                           id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:44.809] >> NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:45.309] << FINDNODE/v4                           id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:45.309] >> NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:45.810] << FINDNODE/v4                           id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:45.810] >> NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:46.310] << FINDNODE/v4                           id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:46.311] >> NEIGHBORS/v4                          id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:46.798] >> PING/v4                               id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:46.799] << PONG/v4                               id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:46.799] >> ENRREQUEST/v4                         id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
TRACE[07-27|19:40:46.800] << ENRRESPONSE/v4                        id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err=nil
DEBUG[07-27|19:40:46.801] ENR request failed                       id=823bff4a7b152c34 addr=172.25.0.102:30303 err="invalid IP in response record: loopback address from non-loopback host"
DEBUG[07-27|19:40:46.801] Revalidated node                         b=12 id=823bff4a7b152c34 checks=2
```

EDIT: Specifying a `static-nodes.json` file under `<datadir>` leads to synced miners. However, using the bootnode still leads to a `Findenode failed` error.

Comment: I am not a specialist, but you need to learn about --nat extip:realIPofYour POd for starting your nodes. Bad idea to run 2 nodes for PoA (if one of node stopped blockchain stopped to) enough one signing node for Poa work (without any bootnodes else)
Try to make like in this tutorial (WITH ONE SIGNING NODE) https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8
For kubernetes there is another tutorial (but not for PoA)
https://imti.co/ethereum-kubernetes/

Comment: Running it with geth Tavum (v1.9.21) solved the issue.